# MS OneNote installed on Windows 8.1 through Store - can I create a local notebook?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I installed the OneNote app available for Microsoft Surface Windows 8.1 on my Surface Pro through the store.

OneNote works fine and I am able to create notebooks, but they all get synched to Skydrive and I can't seem to change that. I'd like to have a local notebook for pictures and items I do not want to share with the world.

All of the technical tips I've read say I should be able to right-click on the notebook and choose its save location. But any of the notebooks I've created, all I have the OneNote panel and when I right-click the notebook the only option I have is to sync that notebook or all of them.

Is there any way I can create a new notebook, or change an existing notebook, to save to my local PC only?

(comment - I've seen some pushback in discussions about WHY someone would want to do this - I would prefer to just find out if it's possible, and how.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

**[Free version](http://onenote.com)** of OneNote stores all notebooks exclusively on OneDrive.

**[Paid version](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/OneNote-2013-Non-Commercial/productID.260245500)** is adding capabilities to record audio/video and to work standalone, ***without OneDrive storage***.

Comment: I think this might not be the case totally now with OneDrive 2013, but it is the case for the onedrive on my surface so thanks for the answer.